# Creating Android Notifications That Display As Puzzle Piece

Tags: android, notifications, puzzle, unlock

I am currently writing an Android app that creates notifications. It successfully creates the notification but I was wondering if there was a way to get my created notification to show up as a puzzle piece if there is an unread notification (the same kind of notification when you have an unread textmessage or have missed calls).

I have looked around the net and haven't seen anything like this around. I am not sure if other droid phones have this feature but it is on the Samsung Galaxy S Captivate.

Any Suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Below is the puzzle piece I am referring to if you are unsure of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a custom Lock Screen of Samsung TouchWiz. This means that it isn't part of the Android SDK. I don't know if Samsung provides an API to interact with this lock screen (I would say no), and in case it does exist, then it will only work in devices with TouchWiz.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a puzzle-piece icon for a background image. This could then be used in a custom layout group which will also need an ImageView for the envelope and a TextView for the number (side by side). When a notification is created, create one of these custom layout groups and display it as required.

You haven't given details such as if a second notification is created, does that increase the number by 1 or does it create a second puzzle piece and slot it in somewhere else on the 'puzzle-board' background?

It looks like you only need 1 puzzle-piece icon as the pieces are all the same (with just a 90 degree rotation).